# How do I set it up to add a script as default when I create a new form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have created a script that will process the results when my form is submitted. This works fine for my script I have been using for testing. I want it to use it for all my forms.

How do I set it up to add a script as default when I create a new form?

I've looked into add-ons and web-apps, both seem not the right way for my solution.

**Perspective**
As I teacher I decided to give homework using Google Forms. To keep track of how homework is made, I need to keep track of who makes homework and how well it's made. The class list is (ofcourse) in a non-google system.

Comment: Have a look at the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api)

Comment: it seems to me the REST API is for managing Google Apps Script from a remote source (like a private server). I need my script in the Google Apps environment to run for every form my organization has.

Comment: Just wanted to understand better. Does your script do scoring? or just tracking submissions?

Comment: The form is a quiz and I uses the scores Google Forms gives to the questions. My script does not add scores, just checks the results and processes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that seems best for my case is creating a template for my form with the script. All new created forms will have the script. I hope this will help others.